# LINQ Query - Dynamic PIvot on Date

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, pivot

I'm working on a application that uses Entity Framework 4 to retrieve data from a database and then display it in a WPF DataGrid. The data I retrieve looks like this:

```
SCHEMATIC_ID    SERIAL_NUM  OUTAGE_DATE POSITION    COMMENTS
1G1111G111G1    1199        4/17/2003   10          Filler
1G1111G111G1    1199        5/21/2004   10          Filler
1G1111G111G2    1962        4/17/2003   3           Filler
1G1111G111G2    1962        5/21/2004   3           Filler
1G1111G111G1    2017        5/21/2004   9           Filler
1G1111G111G1    226         5/21/2004   8   
1G1111G111G1    290         5/21/2004   6   
1G1111G111G1    291         5/21/2004   5   
1G1111G111G1    295         5/21/2004   1   
1G1111G111G1    65450       5/21/2004   3   
1G1111G111G1    65451       5/21/2004   9           Filler
1G1111G111G1    65453       5/21/2004   6           Filler
1G1111G111G1    65458       4/17/2003   6   
1G1111G111G1    65458       5/21/2004   6   
1G1111G111G1    65459       5/21/2004   7
```

I need to pivot the data so that the date becomes a dynamic column heading (I don't know the number of dates there will be) and the position falls under the date per each SN/Schematic. It should look like this:

```
SCHEMATIC_ID    SERIAL_NUM  4/17/2003   5/21/2004   COMMENTS
1G1111G111G1    1199        10          10          Filler
1G1111G111G2    1962        3           3           Filler
1G1111G111G1    2017                    9           Filler
1G1111G111G1    226                     8   
1G1111G111G1    290                     6   
1G1111G111G1    291                     5   
1G1111G111G1    295                     1   
1G1111G111G1    65450                   3   
1G1111G111G1    65451                   9           Filler
1G1111G111G1    65453                   6           Filler
1G1111G111G1    65458       6           6   
1G1111G111G1    65459                   7
```

I found [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd619109-ed42-446c-8808-c5c8791f84bb/dynamic-linq-pivot?forum=csharplanguage) on the Microsoft forum but I have been unsuccessful because I don't really understand the Lambda inside of the select statement.

This is what I've been working from

```
var query = (from p in context.PARTS_STAGING
              where p.TN == SelectedTN
              group p by new { p.PART_SERIAL_NUM, p.PART_SCH_NUM, p.COMMENTS } into g
              select new PartStaging()
              {
                   SerialNumber = g.Key.PART_SERIAL_NUM,   
                   SchNumber = g.Key.PART_SCH_NUM,
                   Position = g.GroupBy(f => f.OUTAGE_DATE).Select(m => new { ?? }) // <- This is the part I can't get to work
                   Comments = g.Key.COMMENTS
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a map of your data SCHEMATIC_ID    SERIAL_NUM  OUTAGE_DATE POSITION    COMMENTS.
The assume you have a collection of those things. Lamba integrates with LINQ so it pays to put in training time, but real quick here some samples with that scheama in mind

```
using (var db = new mydatabaseentities()){
   var stuff = db.Database.SqlQuery<theTypeAbove>("Select * from table where...", SQLParms);
   var filtered = stuff.Where(p=>p.SCHEMATIC_ID < 1000).Select(p=>p.OUTAGE_DATE_POSITION).ToList();
   var filtered2 = stuff.Where(p=>p.SERIAL_NUM = 12345);
   var filtered3 = stuff.Where(p=>COMMENTS.Length>100); 
}

//IF you were able to get complete maps from EF and tables have good relations you could do this:

using (var db= new mydatabaseentitite()){
  var stuff = db.MyTable.Where(p=>p.SCHEMATIC_ID==99);

}
```

In first example it shows how to issue a raw sql query which sometimes is necessary, but not that the results are projected into the entity type that was generated by EF.  The Filtered example shows how to select just one field.  While the Filtered2 example shows how to select all the fields based on the where criteria.  Filtered3 shows how to use string functions to filter data in the db.  Finally the 2nd example shows how to do everything in EF "not using raw sql but just LINQ".

Lambdas are simply methods that say in essence do it here rather than there.  They're build upon the concept of an iterator so you don't have to set up foreach loops.  LINQ has tons of methods that support Lambdas and therefore LINQ itself is worth it's weight in Gold.  This makes learning Lamdas highly profitable for your production.